# What is the correct etiquette for answering a question where an answer has been given in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, unanswered-questions

I've come across quite a few questions where I believe one or more acceptable answers have been given, but in the comments rather than as an answer.

In cases like these, would it be acceptable for me to post an answer which does little more than reiterate what has been said in the comments, but nonetheless does answer the question?

It kinda annoys me that there are questions which remain "unanswered" despite the fact an answer has been given (and sometimes acknowledged by the questioner) in the comments, but I wouldn't want to post an answer if it might cause conflict or is somehow against the rules or etiquette.

Comment: I'm curious about the downvote - is it because you feel I've not shown any research effort, or the question is not useful, or both? FWIW, I did search both Google and SE before posting and didn't find either of the answers proposed as duplicated.